# do i put tags for color and font of a piece of text in the same <h1>bracket</h1> or separate ones?

Tags: html, css, fonts

[image: this is the code, highlighted line where the problem is, i've tried several different fonts and the text just stays the same? i've got the tag right no?]

this is the code, highlighted line where the problem is, i've tried several different fonts and the text just stays the same? i've got the tag right no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use one `style` attribute.

`<h1 style="color:white; font-family:Helvetica;">arial</h1>`